# Printing a row of asterisks

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in c++ where I must print an n number of asterisk rows in increments of n+1. Basically the flow of the program must run like this:

1 *

2 *********

3 **********

My program right now only prints out an ordered row of asterisks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    char s = '*';

    cout << "Input x" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Input y" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
    {
        cout << i<<"# ";
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << s;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this program print asterisks in n+1 order?

Comment: hint: look at your for loop end condition

Answer (score 1):

You want to add one more asterisk so add one to the inner loop:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i+1; j++)
```

The inner loop is the loop printing the number of asterisks. For each time it runs it prints one asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

The internal loop has to be defined the following way

```
    for (int j = x; j <= i; j++)
    {
        cout << s;
    }
```

That is instead of `int j = 1` there has to be `int j = x`

At least I got the following result

```
Input x 3
Input y 

3# *
4# **
5# ***
6# ****
7# *****
8# ******
9# *******
10# ********
```

If you want that numbers start with 1 then change `cout << i<<"# ";` to `cout << i - x + 1 <<"# ";`
Or you can write `cout << setw( 2 ) << i - x + 1 <<"# ";` provided that you included header `<iomanip>`

**EDIT:**

If you meant the following output

```
3# *
4# ***
5# *****
6# *******
7# *********
8# ***********
9# *************
10# ***************
```

then the control statement of the inner loop should be wriiten as

```
for (int j = x; j < 2 * i - x + 1; j++)
```

Comment: What I need to is is be able to duplicate the stars after each iteration, meaning:

Line 1 = *
Line 2 = *** (because we add 1+2)
Line 3 = ***** (because we add 2 + 3) so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My thanks goes to the contributors that helped me get to this answer:

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= _howManyPrintLines; i++)
            {
                cout << i<<"# ";
                n = i-1;//helps ensure that n stays at the right number
                n = n + i;//stores each index of i and adds them
                for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    cout << s;          
                }
                cout << endl;       
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is using string

```
enter code here  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string a = "*";
string c;
int x;
for (x=0; x<5; x++)
{
  c+=a;
  cout<<c<<endl;
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Altered your code a bit to only print 1 extra asterisk per row:

```
int n, row;

cout << "How many rows do you want to print? ";
cin >> row;

for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
    n = i - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```